# How to change elfinder default upload path?

Tags: elfinder

I just want to ask how can I change the default upload directory for the elfinder?
In the connection.php have something like this.

```
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',   // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path'          => '../files/',         // path to files (REQUIRED)
            'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'accessControl' => 'access'             // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        )
    )
);
```

Now all the uploads will go to the directory files.
This is my folder structure:

```
mywebsite
- video_images
  - 1
    - 1.jpg
  - 2
    - 2.jpg
- plugin
  - elfinder
    -files
```

I want to change the default directory to the video_images. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `path` to the directory that you want. Should be something like this:

```
 'path' => '../../../mywebsite/video_images', // path to files (REQUIRED)
```

You need to make sure that the user running PHP has access to read / write that folder and this should do it.